# How to include sass and correct syntax

Tags: ruby, wordpress, sass

How do I get my website revering to the compass functions? I understand that I have to upload the scss file in my theme directory (using wordpress). But the `config.rb` file must be there as well right? Do I upload the scss directory and css directory just like compass made it for me on my computer?

Further I would like to know when I use `.sass` for the file. I am using sass syntax, but my file name ends with `.scss`. I am wondering if this maybe one of the errors I am dealing with. Do I need a `.sass` file if I am working with `extend`/`import`?

I get an error while compiling that points out this line on my config.rb

```
# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass stylesheets scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
preferred_syntax = :scss
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not to upload your sass file. Your site does not need the sass file.

1. You must write your css in SASS format. http://sass-lang.com/guide
2. Compile your sass to css via sass comipler. http://sass-lang.com/install
3. Now the output, which is a css, should be used in your site

So the sample.sass:

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

Will be sample.css

```
body {
  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}
```

and you can use it in your site.

Comment: great, so I was thinking to complicated :P so you are also saying that I should make a .sass file instead the .scass file I have? I just do not quite understand the instructions that are written in the config.br how to do that..

Comment: SASS and SCSS are just to ways, or to syntax you can write your high-level sass files. Two find which to use http://thesassway.com/articles/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better
As you are new to this, I suggest you do not deal with config.br as you may not need it. Just compile your sass to css and put it in your site

Comment: yes thanks, but unfortunately I get an error message while compiling the file that in line  24 is a mistake within the syntax directing me to the config.br file... really sturgling with that problem.